# Javascript RegExp : How to detect space character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a pattern that will return if a string has the following formating:

`yyyy / mm / dd` ( please note that they are 4 spaces in that string ).

The following code is what I have come with so far, but it still can't detect the space character. Any ideas how to make it work ?

```
RegExp( /^\d{4}[\s\/\s]\d{2}[\s\/\s]\d{2}$/g ).test( "1234 / 11 / 22" );    
RegExp( /^\d{4}[ \/ ]\d{2}[ \/ ]\d{2}$/g ).test( "1234 / 11 / 22" );
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `[]` all over the place? I don't see a need for  character classes here.

Answer (score 1):

```
regexp = /^\d{4}\s\/\s\d{2}\s\/\s\d{2}$/g;
```

Comment: It is common here to accept an answer if it solved your problem. Please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

```
RegExp( /^\d{4}\s\/\s\d{2}\s\/\s\d{2}/g ).test( "1234 / 11 / 22" );
```